# WPF item list for telegram-logger like Windows Media Player playlist

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I want to create a data Logger for bus-communication in wpf. The bus-communication consists of telegrams that contain source adress, target adress, type of command, length of telegram and the actual data. 
I want to represent those telegrams in an ListBox that looks like a media player playlist. The ListBox should be divided into columns for source adress, target adress etc.
By clicking on an element you should select the complete row.
If you click on an element twice slowly you should be able to select the contained text of the row.
If you doubleclick on an element fast a window with detailed data should open.
The first Row should contain the name of the columns with the ability to sort the data by clicking on it (with highlighting only the element on mouse over).

Is such an Control already availiable for WPF (with source code)? IF not how can i create an Control like the windows media playlist in wpf?

Thanks,
kyon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control you want is the `DataGrid`. It will do many of the things you requested out of the box, but not all.

To enable opening a details dialog, you will need to handle the `MouseDoubleClick` event. In the handler, cast the `sender` as a `DataGrid` and get the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` property to determine which telegram to show in the details dialog.

There is a built in editing capability, which would allow you to select the text in a cell, but the user could also change this text. I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but there is probably a way you could just cancel any change to the text if you wanted read-only.